# how to send multiple row to mysql at same time(like bulk copy)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am using asp.net + Mysql.

I have multiple rows in my dataset; I have to store the rows in my database table. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the insert statement ..

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

this inserts 3 rows

```
a | b | c
--+---+--
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6 
7 | 8 | 9
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Comment: i am using stored procedure.. so i have to pass data from my front end